# SelectedRow property could not be found in WPF

Tags: wpfdatagrid

Error'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

also i cannot access SelectedRow property ... same error happens as above mention . 
am i really missing any directives or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows.DataGrid : You  can access items by DaaGrid.Items and then Casting it to specific type what u want. you will get  DataGrid.SelectedItem Instead of DataGrid.SelectedRow